# How would I go about linking libcsv library to my GCC compiler?

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker, g++

I'm working on a project that requires parsing of a csv file, and I dicided to use rgamble's libcsv library for this job.

I followed through his install guide:

> ```
> ./configure
> make
> make check
> make install
> ```

and it seems that everything was install properly. I have even updated, upgraded, and install build-essential to my ubuntu and debian WSL terminals to try to get this to work.

For some reason, when attempting to compile my files, using the following command

> gcc -g -Wall -L./libcsv -libcsv *.c -o main

and

> gcc -g -Wall *.c -Llibcsv -o main -llibcsv

I'm always presented with this compiling error:

> In file included from WriterProcess.c:1:
> headers.h:14:10: fatal error: libcsv/csv.h: No such file or directory
> 14 | #include <libcsv/csv.h>
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.
> In file included from main.c:1:
> headers.h:14:10: fatal error: libcsv/csv.h: No such file or directory
> 14 | #include <libcsv/csv.h>
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.

my header look like so:

```
// core
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// #include <wiringPi.h>
#include <unistd.h> // sleep
#include <errno.h>

// WriterProcess
#include <stdlib.h> // sizeof
#include <dirent.h> // file handling

// External Library for CSV
#include <libcsv/csv.h>
```

Yeah, I'm pretty stuck, so any help is very appreciated!

edit:
re-read the isntructions again, and found my mistake, but the problem still persists.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Try replacing #include "libcsv/csv.h" with  #include <csv.h> and
-llibcsv with -lcsv.

Comment: The header csv.h is located /usr/include and so should be used as #include <csv.h>. The library is libcsv.so and so must be linked as -lcsv.